# Repeater bound with two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project in asp.net. I have used two nested repeaters to show status and comments on that status. The nested repeater is bound to a data source which has two tables. Now when I #Eval the value of column of second table it is showing a *not contain property name* error.

```
  <ItemTemplate>

        <div  style="height:285px;">
        <img src='ProfilePic/<%#Eval("ProfilePic")%>' width="100" height="100" alt="" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkfrndname" OnClick="lnkfrndname_Click" CommandName="frndname" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' runat="server"> <u><%#Eval("Firstname")%> <%#Eval("LastName")%></u></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <%#Eval("StatusText")%>
        <br />

        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfstatusid" Value='<%# Eval("StatusId") %>' runat="<asp:Repeater ID="replike" runat="server">
            < <asp:Literal ID="ltlstatuscomm" Text='<%#Eval("CommentText") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal>

        </ItemTemplate>
        </ </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

.cs

```
protected void rephomecontent_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            HiddenField hf = e.Item.FindControl("hfstatusid") as HiddenField;

        if (hf != null)
        {
            Repeater rep = e.Item.FindControl("replike") as Repeater;

            if (rep != null)
            {


                int statusid = int.Parse(hf.Value.ToString());
                DataSet ds = new StatusLikeInfoAction().ViewStatusLike(statusid);
                rep.DataSource = ds;
                rep.DataBind();
             }
          }
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wound be good if you bind the repeater with Datatable instead of DataSet containing multiple table.

First Analyze whether you want to bind

> ds.Tables[0]

Or

> ds.Tables[1]

then bind the repeater as follows

```
rep.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Or

```
rep.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
```

as per your choices

Comment: thanks it worked ,but just for curiosity what if i need to bind repeater with both tables